# Node querystring parsing and character encoding.

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code:

```
var qs = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    if ('/' == req.url) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
        res.end([
            '<form method="post" action="/url">',
            '<h1>My form</h1>',
            '<fieldset>',
            '<label>Personal information</label>',
            '<p>What is your name?</p>',
            '<input type="text" name="name">',
            '<p><button>Submit</button></p>',
            '</form>'
        ].join(''));
    } else if ('/url' == req.url && 'POST' == req.method) {
        var body = '';

        req.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', function () {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
            res.end('<p>Your name is: <strong>' + qs.parse(body).name + '</strong></p>');
        });
    }
}).listen(3000);
```

Lets say i write my swedish name "Anders Östman" name in the input field and POST the form. Everything seems to work fine, except that my name is output as **Anders ï¿½stman**. The charatcher "Ö" get trashed... I guess this have something to do with character encoding and I need to set/convert the parsed object to UTF-8.

**Q:** Is there a way to qs.parse() directly into a UTF-8 object? Or does object does'nt have encoding? Do i need to encode the object value when i output it instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure the browser sends the form data properly encoded, try adding an explicit encoding header:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'});
```

To debug this, try adding

```
 console.log(body)
```

to the second branch. If it says

```
name=Anders+%D6stman
```

the browser is still sending Latin-1 (which is wrong). It should be

```
name=Anders+%C3%96stman
```

Comment: Does'nt work. Neither does this: `'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'`

Comment: @AndersÖstman: make sure to add the header to both parts and reload the server.

Comment: I have tried both `encoding=utf-8` and `charset=utf-8`, on both places... and restarted/reloaded the server!
still no Å Ä Ö =)

Comment: @AndersÖstman: try adding a console.log (see edit). What does it say?

Comment: The raw body output is: name=Anders+%D6stman, so i guess that the browser is sending Latin-1. If I look the the header of the rendered POST page, i see that it's encoded to utf-8. 

So the problem seems to be in the form.

Comment: @AndersÖstman: when you open the form page, what encoding does your browser indicate? (View Page Info in FF, Tools/Encoding in Chrome)? Have you restarted the browser?

Comment: Hmmm... if i check this in Chrome/tool is says "Västeuropeiskt (ISO-8859-1)" on both pages... The browser is restared and cache cleared.

Comment: @AndersÖstman: BTW, it should be "charset", not "encoding" - my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the `Content-Type` for *both* the form *and* the POST response to `text/html; charset=utf-8`. After that you will see the expected result (I tested it locally):

```
var qs = require('querystring');
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    if ('/' == req.url) {
        res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
        res.end([
            '<form method="post" action="/url">',
            '<h1>My form</h1>',
            '<fieldset>',
            '<label>Personal information</label>',
            '<p>What is your name?</p>',
            '<input type="text" name="name">',
            '<p><button>Submit</button></p>',
            '</form>'
        ].join(''));
    } else if ('/url' == req.url && 'POST' == req.method) {
        var body = '';

        req.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        req.on('end', function () {
            res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'});
            res.end('<p>Your name is: <strong>' + qs.parse(body).name + '</strong></p>');
        });
    }
}).listen(3000);
```

You could alternatively set the charset in the html as `meta` tags in the `<head>` with:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">`

or for HTML5:

`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this was some problems in the cache or similiar... i tried in another browser, and it worked. Then i made a total cache deletion of chrome, and got it to work there aswell!